# Jenkins "Need to list all UNUSED PLUGINS IN JENKINS"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I need to list all unused plugins in jenkins

How can we list all unused plugins in Jenkins "tried installing Plugin-usage plugin but no detailed information is available.

Comment: You can achieve this by using the [Plugin-Usage plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/plugin-usage-plugin/).

Comment: Usage plugin best option for that but pipelines are less reliable for analysis and must be run first to be analyzed.